# Creating Bordless Windows with custom visual

Tags: wpf

I'd like to create a custom window using WPF that doesn't look like the regular window.
The window I want to create is similar to MacOs window, with title centered (with dropshadow effect), and controls button on left side of the window.

I did create a bordless window, but some questions I have:

1 - How can I set it functionality of maximize, minimize and close buttons in XAML (if it's possible)?
2 - How can I define a window template so every new window I create have the same look and feel?
3 - Is it possible to create the Aqua maximize, minimize and close buttons using only elements from WPF (without using images)? How?
4 - How can I make the window move when dragged?

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example with custom(-izable) drawing and handling of window operations (min, max, size, drag): [WPF adventures (Part III) or Windows Style](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ayakhnin/PermaLink,guid,23a7be17-d833-4e45-b498-34ef04d98cb2.aspx)

Window was set to remove any title or border; all window controls, including min/max/close buttons, were defined in the custom code.

**Edit**:
OpenNetCF Blogs seem to experience technical issues and the link doesn't work right now.
As alternative one can use a [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20081006142447/http://blog.opennetcf.com/ayakhnin/PermaLink,guid,23a7be17-d833-4e45-b498-34ef04d98cb2.aspx).

Comment: :) I actually was surprised how perfectly that article matched your question. Well, except for #3, but since all controls are custom you probably can restyle WPF buttons or find a theme that can be used for it.