# How to change the height of title bar in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am unable to set the height of title bar from xaml.I can change the height while inspecting the output window from snoop. how to change the height of title bar from XAML?

Comment: Do you mean title bar of a window? What property are you changing in Snoop that you can't change in XAML?

Comment: In snoop i have changed the height property of title bar.but am unable to made that change in xaml

Comment: If .Net 4.5 or higher you can use the WindowChrome class. The following SO answer has links: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27845491/512365

Answer (score 0):

You can use customizable window for changing the height of title bar.

refer this link
https://wpfwindow.codeplex.com/