# WPF window covers taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I'm creating a custom WPF window with, WindowStyle=None, AllowsTransparency=True, and ResizeMode = CanMinimize.

I have two events(That I created to understand events in WPF), PreviewMouseDoubleClick and PreviewMouseMove.

Here's the XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanMinimize"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding GridBackground}">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here's the Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace CustomWindows
{
    public class CustomWindow : Window
    {
        /* Dependency properties */


        public Brush GridBackground
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(GridBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GridBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GridBackground.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GridBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GridBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(Window), new PropertyMetadata(null));




        /* Constructors */

       static CustomWindow()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomWindow)));
        }   



        /* overriders */

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            PreviewMouseDoubleClick += (s, e) => 
            {
                WindowState = (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized) ? WindowState.Normal : WindowState.Maximized;
            };

            PreviewMouseMove += (s, e) => 
            {
                if(Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    DragMove();
                }
            };

            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }
    }
}
```

On Dragging this window, it covers the taskbar. I am not sure as to why.
Here's the link of the image that describes the behavior I'm talking about:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeujR.jpg [Issue Description Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeujR.jpg)

Also on restoring the window, if the mouse pointer is out of bounds of the window, the focus is still not given to Desktop. If the mouse is manually moved a bit later. Focus is given to Desktop. This behavior seems strange to me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use WindowChrome class in an answer by dss539 at: [How to create custom window chrome in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792275/how-to-create-custom-window-chrome-in-wpf)

.NET 4.5 added a new class that greatly simplifies this.

The WindowChrome class enables you to extend Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) content into the non-client area of a window that is typically reserved for the operating system’s window manager.

You can find a tutorial [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2010/08/25/experiments-with-windowchrome.aspx).

And here's a short example [usage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131515/WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library).