# WPF mouse down and mouseleftbuttonup event conflicts. 1 deactivates the other. (Borderless application)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a **WPF** application that is borderless so I needed to create my own buttons for windows functions and needed to add a `MouseDown` event to allow application to move when clicked and dragged.
The document outline is:

Window
 grid
  canvas
   grid
   stackPanel - this is where my windows close max and min buttons are.

here is the code for the `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="689" Canvas.Top="5">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Minimize" Text="0" FontFamily="Webdings" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Minimize_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Maximize" Text="1" FontFamily="Webdings" Foreground="Black" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MouseLeftButtonUp="Maximize_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Close" Text="r" FontFamily="Webdings" Foreground="Black" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MouseLeftButtonUp="Close_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>

        </StackPanel>
```

When I add the `MouseDown` dragmove method, it cancels out the `StackPanel` and does not allow me to close the application as shown in the code above.
I think the document outline needs a specific order? need some help with maybe understanding how it prioritizes the `event handlers` and if I need to rearrange my document outline.

Comment: Personally I'd rather use the Click event, even if it means using a `<Button>` and overwriting the Template to use a TextBox. But that said, you could probably use the MouseDown event instead of MouseUp to get it working. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6792677/302677) is usually the code I end up using.

Comment: although I did start with buttons and it worked fine however the appearance of the buttons didn't really strike me as "good looking". Which is why I went with the textblock webdings look. (more modern). Referencing:
http://hookscode.com/wpfborderlesswindowcontrols/

Comment: WPF is meant to have "lookless" controls, so if you want the functionality of a Button, it's best to use a `<Button>` control and just overwrite the default `.Template` to make it look however you want. In your case, you could overwrite it to use a `TextBlock` with webdings font.

Comment: can you provide some code to help me maybe try what you're suggesting? I understand what you're saying but I was having issues with basically just the appearance with buttons. (This is my first wpf app that I am designing)

Comment: nvm figured it out, thanks for this! :)

Comment: Good to hear! I posted my answer anyways since I had just finished it, and it might help someone else with the same question :)

Comment: definitely, I appreciate you thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `.DragMove` prevents the `MouseLeftButtonUp` from executing on a `TextBlock`, however the `.Click` event of a Button should work correctly.

If I remember correctly, the `MouseDown` event of a Button does not bubble up the UI tree, so the `MouseDown` event of the parent control (in this case, a StackPanel) does not get executed.

Since you are looking for the functionality of a Button using a different UI, I would recommend just using a `<Button>` that has it's `Template` overwritten.

For example,

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}"
                           FontFamily="Webdings" Foreground="Black">
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It can be used like this :

```
<Button x:Name="Minimize" Text="0" 
        Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonStyle}" 
        Click="Minimize_Click" ... />
```