# Creating an acrylic blur effect in WPF using Direct2D

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, directx, interop

Hi i wanted to create the acrylic blur effect provided by Microsoft for my WPF Application.
I have tried many ways such as using DWM Blur Behind,DwmSetWindowAttribute etc..
but since these methods are not much effective i would like to bring the acrylic blur effect using direct2d (The methods used in UWP by using win2d) gaussian blur method mentioned here:

[Gaussian blur effect - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/gaussian-blur)

since i'm a newbie to DirectX,i need help.

Comment: So, what is your *specific* question?

Comment: Have you tried just using the wpf blur effect?            <Image.Effect>
                <BlurEffect KernelType="Gaussian" Radius="20" />
            </Image.Effect>

Comment: Yes I do  but it only add blur for the bitmap image not for the window

Answer (score 0):

WPF effects can be applied to any UIelement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.effect?view=netcore-3.1

A window is a uielement. Notice the inheritance chain:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window?view=netcore-3.1

You can therefore do:

```
    Title="MainWindow" >
<Window.Effect>
    <BlurEffect KernelType="Gaussian" Radius="20" />
</Window.Effect>
```

The effect is not applied to window chrome.

If you want window chrome to be blurred then you would have to provide custom window chrome of your own.

[How to create custom window chrome in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792275/how-to-create-custom-window-chrome-in-wpf)

If you don't need window chrome at all you could set the windowstyle to none.

Comment: i already have a transparent window which i created using setWindowCompositionAttribute() -- AccentState-Invalid when i applied the blur effect it only affects the child elements which are opaque. what i need is to make the whole window to blur (more blur radius than DWM Blur)