# Question on: Creating Custom Window Chrome in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my `WPF` app I'm trying to create a `Custom Chrome Window` [Ref: [WindowChrome]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1). I followed [Restyle Your Window](https://www.eidias.com/blog/2014/1/27/restyle-your-window) article. I created `Resource Dictionary file` along with its code-behind in my project, as shown below. I then referenced the resource dictionary in the app.xaml file (also shown below). As you can see, the `x:key` value of the `Style` tag in `resource dictionary` file is `CustomWindowStyle`. **Question**: How do I assign the Window the Style `CustomWindowStyle`?

**MyResourceDictionaryWindowStyle.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="MyWPFProject.WindowStyle"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWPFProject">

    <Style x:Key="CustomWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="30"
                              CornerRadius="4"
                              GlassFrameThickness="0"
                              NonClientFrameEdges="None"
                              ResizeBorderThickness="5"
                              UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="5,30,5,5">
                            <AdornerDecorator>
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </AdornerDecorator>
                        </Border>

                        <DockPanel Height="30"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   LastChildFill="False">

                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" />

                            <Button x:Name="btnClose"
                                    Width="15"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Click="CloseClick"
                                    Content="X"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />


                            <Button x:Name="btnRestore"
                                    Width="15"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Click="MaximizeRestoreClick"
                                    Content="#"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />

                            <Button x:Name="btnMinimize"
                                    Width="15"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Click="MinimizeClick"
                                    Content="_"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />
                        </DockPanel>

                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MyResourceDictionaryWindowStyle.xaml.cs**:

```
using System;
 .......
using System.Windows;

namespace MyWPFProject
{
    public partial class WindowStyle : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public WindowStyle()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CloseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = (Window)((FrameworkElement)sender).TemplatedParent;
            window.Close();
        }

        private void MaximizeRestoreClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = (Window)((FrameworkElement)sender).TemplatedParent;
            if (window.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Normal)
            {
                window.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
            }
            else
            {
                window.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
            }
        }

        private void MinimizeClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = (Window)((FrameworkElement)sender).TemplatedParent;
            window.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWPFProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
       <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" Click="btnTest_Click"/>
       ......
       ......
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**UPDATE**:

**App.xaml**:

According to user `@Simon Stanford`'s suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44933846/1232087): All you have to do is reference the resource dictionary in your app.xaml file and then assign the Window the Style CustomWindowStyle. So I have referenced the Resource Dictionary as follows. **Question** now is: How do I assign the Window the Style CustomWindowStyle?

```
<Application x:Class="MyWOFProject.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWOFProject"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionaryWindowStyle.xaml"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create custom window chrome in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792275/how-to-create-custom-window-chrome-in-wpf)

Comment: @TomJoney The user `@Simon Stanford`'s [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44933846/1232087) in your suggested link is almost doing what I have done. But that user is advising: All you have to do is reference the resource dictionary in your app.xaml file `and then assign the Window the Style CustomWindowStyle`. The last part of his advice is what I looking on how to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not really sure what you didn't get from there but it seems as though you have a gap in your knowledge about ResourceDictionaries so I'd recommend having a read of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references for help regarding the matter and help referencing.

Comment: @TomJoney Your link provided a general understanding on the subject. But, its sublink [Every FrameworkElement can have a ResourceDictionary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#every-frameworkelement-can-have-a-resourcedictionary) together a response from `@thatfuy` helped me resolve the issue. Since `Window` is also a `FrameworkElement ` you set its attribute as `Style="{StaticResource CustomWindowStyle}"` as user `@thatguy` shows in his `MainWindow.xaml` code below. Thank you for providing the assistance.

Comment: I am glad you have figured it out - at first, it was hard to interpret what you needed help with so I provided a link that I thought would give you some more understanding. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I assign the Window the Style CustomWindowStyle?

Merge your `MyResourceDictionaryWindowStyle` in `App.xaml`. See the example below. Your project might have a different name than `MyWPFProject.App` and the `Source` of the resource dictionary depends on where your custom resource dictionary is actually located in the project, so you should adapt both accordingly, as well as the `StartupUri` for your main window.

```
<Application x:Class="MyWPFProject.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
   <Application.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyWPFProject;component/MyResourceDictionaryWindowStyle.xaml"/>
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then just set the style as `StaticResource` in your window.

```
<Window x:Class="MyWPFProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Style="{StaticResource CustomWindowStyle}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <!-- ...your XAML code -->
</Window>
```

Comment: I have added an **UPDATE** section with my `App.xaml` file content and a comment. Would that work?